# Bug with framed, listings and xcolor are together

Tags: listings, color, framed

When using a combination of the packages `framed`, `listings`, and `xcolor`, that causes a strange bug, that I cannot manage to fix.

The problem is that, when a box (made with the `framed` package, and `fcolorbox`) contains a listing just before a page breaks, the rest of the block appears blank on the next page. Moreover, the block on the firxt page is not framed anymore.

[image]

This does not happens if I use fbox instead of fcolorbox.

The minimal example is the following:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstnewenvironment{python}{\lstset{language=python}}{}

\renewcommand*{\FrameCommand}{%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{\FrameRule}\setlength{\fboxsep}{\FrameSep}%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{framed}{Block}
\blindtext

Foo

\blindtext

\begin{python}
def f(x):
    foo
\end{python}
THIS NEVER APPEARS
\blindtext
\end{framed}
End of block
\end{document}
```

What I am looking for is any kind of workaround, not necessarily a full solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `\color{black}` after `\end{python}` solves the problem (but a color stack warning appears). It seems that somehow the "white" background becomes also the text color after the `python` environment.

### EDIT

Use **mdframed**. A simple

```
\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip]
...
\end{mdframed}
```

produces what you are looking for. The environment is customizable in many ways.

Comment: Haha, brilliant! This is indeed what is happening: the text after the page break becomes the background colour! Thanks!

Comment: There is still the issue of the framing, though. The frame on the first page disappears...

Comment: Sorry. It has to do with the inner workings of `framed` that gathers its contents and all the catcode tricks of **listings** cannot be performed properly. I believe that **mdframed** can do a better job.

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant. Exactly the right solution. This package `mdframed` seems much more reliable than `framed`. I also prefer the result.